# Rails: Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

rails generate scaffold controller sportler name:string 
rails generate model einheit ... sportler_id:integer

**/app/controllers/sportlers_controller.rb** 
..
 def add_einheit
    sportler = Sportler.find(params[:id])
    @einheit = Einheit.new(:sportler => sportler)
    render :template => "einheits/edit"
  end
..

**/app/views/sportles/index.html.erb** - when i cut this source code below the route error 
doesnet appear anymore

..

```
<td><br>
  <%= link_to "Trainingseinheit hinzufügen", :action => "add_einheit", :id => sportler %><br>
</td><br>
```

..

**routes.rb**

FITAPP2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :sportlers

**Routing Error**

No route matches {:action=>"add_einheit", :id=>#groesse: "3", created_at: "2012-12-27 15:56:04", updated_at: "2012-12-27 15:56:04">, 
:controller=>"sportlers"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Jordie, I just reformatted your whole post but then you deleted the changes. [Learn about StackOverflow-flavored markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As routing error suggest you should "try running **rake routes** for more information on available routes."
The point is you obviously have not specify route rule for add_einheit method

Comment: How can i define such a rule?

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :sportlers
```

This code will only creates routes about CRUD actions(create,new,edit,update vss...)
To use "add_einheit" actions edit routes.rb ;

```
resources :sportlers do
    member do
        get "add_einheit"
    end
end
```

If you send a parameter like "id" use
    "member do"
else use
    "collection do"
in your routes.rb file.

Comment: after i did this, the error doenst occur but when i click on the link the view doesnt appear

Comment: That's because your template isn't in the right place for this action.  Either move your template to 'sportlers/add_einheit' or force it to render your template using `render :action => :edit, :controller => :einheits`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a html file under sportlers view folder, 
like view/sportlers/add_einheit.html.erb ?

Comment: no, but _form.html.erb, edit.html.erb, new.html.erb, show.html.erb

Comment: add_einheit is a method in my controller

Comment: your html file has to have the same name with your method, if you do not point a spesific html file in your method block. so if you have a add_einheit method in sportlers controller and you want to render a html file from this method, you set /sportlers/add_einheit.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

I took Kaders solution.
It functions but now i geht the next Routing Error. action => sportlers/update_einheit doesnt function. I dont understand the princip.

FITAPP2::Application.routes.draw do
resources :sportlers do
    member do
        get "add_einheit"
        **get "update_einheit"**
    end
end
end

I try to extends the routes above with a second entry get update_einheit - it doenst function
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"update_einheit", :id=>#, :controller=>"sportlers"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

rake routes:

add_einheit_sportler GET    /sportlers/:id/add_einheit(.:format)    sportlers

## add_einheit

update_einheit_sportler GET    /sportlers/:id/update_einheit(.:format) sportlers

## update_einheit

```
          sportlers GET    /sportlers(.:format)                    sportlers
```

## index

```
                    POST   /sportlers(.:format)                    sportlers
```

## create

```
       new_sportler GET    /sportlers/new(.:format)                sportlers
```

## new

```
      edit_sportler GET    /sportlers/:id/edit(.:format)           sportlers
```

## edit

```
           sportler GET    /sportlers/:id(.:format)                sportlers
```

## show

```
                    PUT    /sportlers/:id(.:format)                sportlers
```

## update

```
                    DELETE /sportlers/:id(.:format)                sportlers
```

## destroy

Comment: If you took that solution, then please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the arrow to the left of accepted answer.